# What does this highlight text mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, manga

[image]

First bubble: 制服姿もあと何回見れるか分からないなって

Second bubble: いふえおひえはう。。。っ

So the speaker in the second bubble is giving a blowjob to another person and I can't search it up in a dictionary Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Most probably it's simply not meant to be read. As it is, it describes what the character says with mouth full, and just like "#!@?$". It could be guessable with a larger context.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, Japanese people can understand such text by intuition and experience.

Maybe,

- "いふえお" mean "いつでも"
- "ひえはう" mean "見れます"

To your understanding, please try speak "いつでも見れます" with something big in your mouth.